# Multiplying floats "manually" with integer operations

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, multiplication, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to implement a floating point multiply without using FP hardware instructions.

I think my code works for the sign bit and exponents bits, but not the mantissa.

**The general idea:**
1. Add exponents of those two numbers.
2. Multiply their mantissas.
3. Normalize the mantissa.
4. Add to exponent the part got from normalizing mantissa.
I ignore the sign bit for now since I test it on values higher than 0.

And here is the problem: I tried to multiply those two mantissas and then - since the result would be in two registers edx:eax - shifting bits one by one from edx to eax meanwhile increasing exponent.
But it doesn't seem to work, so I wonder if my idea is good, or maybe there is some better way to do it?

---

Here is what I have already written in MASM:

```
mov eax, [ebp+8] ;put into eax one of numbers to multiply
mov ecx, a ;in ecx is second number to multiply, constant = 1.8

and ecx, 7F800000H ;mask to get exponent
and eax, 7F800000H

shr ecx, 23
shr eax, 23

sub ecx, 127
sub eax, 127

add ecx, eax ;exponent of the final number - later should be added part got from mantissa

mov eax, [ebp+8]
mov edx, a
and eax, 007FFFFFH ;getting mantissa
and edx, 007FFFFFH

; editor's note: unsure if there were any unlisted instructions
; between the two code in the original

mul edx    ; multiply the mantissas

mov ebx, 0

spr:
    cmp edx, 0 ;check if edx is cleared out
    jne przesun
    je dalej

przesun:
    inc ecx
    shr eax, 1 ;making space for new bit
    shr edx, 1 ;put bit to CF
    bts eax, 31 ;putting bit from CF   ; Bug #1, see Michael's answer
    jmp spr

dalej:
    shr eax, 7
    shl ecx, 23
    add eax, ecx ;result of multiplying
```

**The result is 0 for every number I tried multiplying with 1.8.**
(atm I test it on number 15, so the result should be 27)

Comment: _"shifting bits one by one from edx to eax meanwhile increasing exponent"_. I don't see that being done in the code you've posted. You should post the code that contains the problem you're asking about. _"But it doesn't seem to work"_. Define _"it doesn't work"_. What happens?

Comment: Thank u for respond. I added the missing code. What happens - the result is incorrect.

Comment: @Kate: since you're asking for people to debug your code, unless you expect people to assemble this themselves and single-step through it in their own debugger, you should list both the value you wanted and the value you actually got.  "result is incorrect" adds almost zero new information over "doesn't work".

Comment: I was more asking about if my general idea is correct, cause i believe that there is no point of debugging if i'm wrong from the beggining. The value i wanted is 27, the result of multiplying 15*1.8. The value i got, what i've already written is 0. It's 0 for every number i want to multiply with 1.8.

Comment: @Kate: You should edit that into the question near the top.  Also describe in words what your algorithm is.  Reading potentially-buggy assembly code is not an easy way for people to understand your current algorithm.  Getting the algo right, and implementing it in asm, are actually two completely separate things.  You could write a correct implementation in C, for example.  Then you could compare compiler output with your hand-written asm.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links, and a quick guide to single-stepping through asm code while watching registers change.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I added things, which u told me to add. I hope it's what u expected. I will try to write it in C. Tell me if u will need more information. Got one more, hope that not stupid question... Will multiplying two mantissas(as that is fraction part) by MUL give a correct result?

Comment: @Kate: I'm not an FP expert, but 32x32->64bit multiply and then taking the most significant 23 bits of that sounds right.  When I asked about expected value vs. actual value, I was talking about integer registers, not the final FP result.  Single-step through your code in a debugger, and find where a register has a value it shouldn't.  Then try to find the earliest point where this happens.  The bug will be there, and it'll be either from a design error, or from instructions not doing what the comments say they're doing.

Comment: @Kate: are you sure you're storing your result into an FP variable that the compiler is actually reading?  Always getting zero sounds suspicious.  You're using visual C++ inline asm, right?  I don't see a `ret` at the end of your code, so I assume this isn't standalone asm.

Answer (score 1):

```
bts eax, 31 ;putting bit from CF
```

^ `BTS` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Quoting from Intel's manual (emphasis added):

> Selects the bit in a bit string (specified with the first operand, called the bit base) at the bit-position designated by
>   the bit offset operand (second operand), stores the value of the bit in the CF flag, **and sets the selected bit in the
>   bit string to 1**. The bit base operand can be a register or a memory location; the bit offset operand can be a register
>   or an immediate value.

So you're always setting the bit to 1, regardless of the value of the bit you just shifted out.

There are other instructions that you can use to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
shrd eax, edx, 1  ; Shift eax 1 bit to the right, with the new MSB shifted in from edx
shr edx,1         ; The shrd above doesn't modify edx, so discard the old LSB of edx
```

or:

```
shr edx, 1   ; CF = edx.0
rcr eax, 1   ; rotate through carry; shift in CF from the left and shift out eax.0
```

Comment: You're right. I picked second option, but it still gives me a wrong result. Is the general idea good or there are some mistakes? I also found one mistake on my own, i forgot to add 127 to the final exponent.

Comment: @Kate: `shrd` is faster than `rcr`, and also allows you to shift multiple bits at once.  You can use 32-`lzcnt` (or `bsr` after testing for non-zero) to find out how many bits to shift.

Answer (score 0):

Your algo sounds reasonable.  This [floating point converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) might be useful quickly see what the bit pattern should be for any given number.

Since your wrong-answer is zero, your remaining bug might not be in your code exactly, but in how you're getting the result back to the rest of your program.  Try with bigger numbers, or set `eax` to non-zero manually in the debugger.

asm style: Your loop that shifts bits from one reg to another is poorly implemented.  (besides the fact it's unneeded, see below).  Instead of an unconditional `jmp` back to a test at the top, you should test&branch at the start to skip the loop if needed, and then put another test&branch at the bottom of the loop to repeat only the instructions that need to be in the loop.

```
; mov ebx, 0    ; was this supposed to be ecx?
                ; ebx doesn't show up anywhere else in your code
xor  ebx, ebx

spr:
    ; cmp edx, 0 ;check if edx is cleared out
    test edx, edx  ; shorter encoding when testing for 0
    jz dalej     ; jz and je are the same instruction
    ; else fall through into the loop.  Your old version used two branches here >.<

przesun:
    inc ecx
    shr eax, 1 ;making space for new bit
    shr edx, 1 ;put bit to CF
    ; bts eax, 31 ;bug, but Michael's answer covered that
    test edx,edx
    jnz  przesun
dalej:
```

Yes, it's better to repeat the test&branch if that reduces jumps.  It may also improve CPU branch prediction performance if some inputs skip the loop, but when they don't they have the same number of iterations.

`test/jcc` is about the same cost as `jcc` alone, but takes more space.

You might be able to save an instruction by taking advantage of the fact
that `shr` sets the Zero flag based on the result.  But prob not in this case, as you need to put the bit into `eax`, which will set flags.

---

When you combine the exponent and mantissa, it would make more sense to use an `or` instruction, instead of `add`.  It's not going to make the code smaller or faster, but the usual way to combine different parts of a bit-field is with `or`.  You don't need or want carry between bits (which won't actually happen because one value is zero everywhere the other can have ones).

```
shr eax, 7    ; mantissa
shl ecx, 23   ; exponent
    ;; add eax, ecx ;result of multiplying
or  eax, ecx  ; combined result
```

Actually, this might be another case where you could use `shrd` instead of two shifts and an `or`.

Or you could work with exponents in their "proper" position, and leave the low 23bits all zero when you add exponents.  Instead of `inc`, you'd add `1<<23`.  (or `shiftcount << 23` without the loop).  You still need to get the mantissa's signs to/from the sign bit.

`xor` might be useful for handling the sign bit.  `a ^ b` has the same sign bit as `a * b`.

---

**Of course, in this case you shouldn't use a loop at all**.  Like I commented on Michael's answer, you should use 32-`lzcnt` to count how many bits there are, then do it with one `shrd`.  You can zero the source reg after with `xor edx, edx`, if you want.   (`bsr`+1 after testing for non-zero, instead of `32-lzcnt`, is an alternative if you want your code to run on CPUs without `lzcnt`)

This should still work for denormal results.  The upper 32 is zero, and the lower 32 has leading zeros.  However, if your exponent is already at the minimum, I guess there's nothing you can do but leave it denormal.

`xor`ing a register with itself the the canonical idiom for zeroing.  It takes fewer instruction bytes than `mov edx, 0`, and is just as fast.  (CPUs recognize it as not depending on the previous value of the register, so it doesn't delay out-of-order execution).

Comment: @Kate: updated my answer with comments about the bit at the end where you combine the mantissa and exponent.